# Using sapply inside sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I need to execute sapply inside another sapply.

This is the working code I have.

```
animal <- c("Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Fish", "Monkey", "Lion", "Dolphin", "Panda")
a <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:7, function(y) rbinom(30, 1, sample(seq(.4, .9, by=.1), 1, prob = NULL))))
colnames(a) <- (animal)
```

I would like to build this data frame 10 time without doing this.

```
animal <- c("Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Fish", "Monkey", "Lion", "Dolphin", "Panda")

a <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:7, function(y) rbinom(30, 1, sample(seq(.4, .9, by=.1), 1, prob = NULL))))
colnames(a) <- (animal)

b <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:7, function(y) rbinom(30, 1, sample(seq(.4, .9, by=.1), 1, prob = NULL))))
colnames(b) <- (animal)

...

j <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:7, function(y) rbinom(30, 1, sample(seq(.4, .9, by=.1), 1, prob = NULL))))
colnames(j) <- (animal)
```

I have tried this without success

```
sapply(letters[1:10], function(z) as.data.frame(sapply(1:7, function(y) rbinom(300, 1, sample(seq(.4, .9, by=.1), 1, prob = NULL)))), colnames(letters[1:10]) <- (animal))
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for `?replicate`

Comment: It is not really clear to me what the output should be. An 80x30 data.frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do this with two `apply` type functions, you can do something like this:

Also you have Eight animals in `animal` and only making 7 columns. So I have shortened `animal`.

Using `lapply` on the outer loop will always return a list, which makes it a bit neater than `sapply` from what I understand you are trying to do.

```
animal <- c("Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Fish", "Monkey", "Lion", "Dolphin")

lapply(1:10, function(x){
  a <- as.data.frame(
    sapply(1:7, function(y) rbinom(30, 1, sample(seq(.4, .9, by=.1), 1, prob = NULL)))
  )
  names(a) <- (animal)
  a
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using sapply, so it is not clear if you want the end result to be a matrix or a list. If you want a matrix as output, then a straightforward approach would be to use your existing code, but start with an expanded vector (animals x replicates).

```
animal.reps = sapply(c("Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Fish", "Monkey", "Lion", "Dolphin", "Panda"), paste, letters[1:10], sep = ".")
a = sapply(animal.reps, function(y) rbinom(30, 1, sample(seq(.4, .9, by=.1), 1, prob = NULL)) )
```

This gives a 30x80 matrix:

```
> dim(a)
[1] 30 80

> a[1:10, 1:10]
      Dog.a Dog.b Dog.c Dog.d Dog.e Dog.f Dog.g Dog.h Dog.i Dog.j
 [1,]     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
 [2,]     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
 [3,]     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
 [4,]     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 [5,]     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0
 [6,]     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     1
 [7,]     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 [8,]     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
 [9,]     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
[10,]     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```